# Can\'t set headers after they are sent error

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

This part of code caused the problem to my app.

```
router.use(function(req, res, next){
  if(req.user){
    res.locals.username = req.user.username
  }else{
    res.redirect('/login');
  }
  next();
});

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('dashboard');
});
```

If I removed the first block, everything worked fine. But the first part have to be there, to act as the auth middleware. But it crashed and I got error of below:

```
_http_outgoing.js:341
    throw new Error('Can\'t set headers after they are sent.');
    ^

Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
```

Comment: Can you please show the code from the controller and action where you get this message?

Comment: @Bilal what controller? my controller is fine. This is my router.js code

Comment: Because this happens when you are redirecting inside an async block and also after that. So it'll be helpful if you can post the code here.

Comment: @bilai you mean login controller? How does that have to do with the auth above? I can run the login page if the above code is removed. I found out the auth logic have issue.

Comment: I am asking about the `controller -> action` code where submitting the login form or the request when you see this error.

Comment: @Bilal does that matter? I have no problem getting the params submitted from the front.

Comment: put return in else "return res.redirect('/login');"

Comment: @AbdulAleem seriously ?

Answer (score 0):

Try returning immediately after performing the `redirect()` to avoid further route handler executions that may also try to set headers. You will also want to check `req.url` before redirecting. For example:

```
router.use(function(req, res, next){
  if (req.user) {
    res.locals.username = req.user.username
  } else if (!/\/login/i.test(req.url)) {
    return res.redirect('/login');
  }
  next();
});
```

This will prevent execution from continuing if you are redirecting the request (`redirect()` sends (the appropriate) headers).

Comment: I got this `GET /login 302 240.929 ms - 56
GET /login 302 245.793 ms - 56
GET /login 302 339.903 ms - 56
GET /login 302 294.324 ms - 56
GET /login 302 298.944 ms - 56
GET /login 302 244.899 ms - 56
GET /login 302 253.586 ms - 56
GET /login 302 2514.778 ms - 56
GET /login 302 242.050 ms - 56
GET /login 302 293.136 ms - 56
GET /login 302 304.390 ms - 56
GET /login 302 302.294 ms - 56
GET /login 302 296.343 ms - 56`

Comment: my `(req.user)` is undefined.

Comment: how does that help? my req.user is not defined, I think I've problem configuring my passport middleware.

Comment: That's what I am saying @Jennifer. Your `req.user` is undefined. The `next()` method is called to further execute the code in the controller. The problem is in your controller not in the middleware.

Comment: @Bilal if I have problem in my controller, why my app is fine if I remove the first block of above code?

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 weak points in the code you provided:

1. It `redirect()` the request and then continue processing it as if nothing happened. It should stop processing the request, in other words not call `next()` after redirect, as @mscdex correctly pointed out.
2. It always redirects the user to the `/login` page if the `user` is not provided. Even if the user is requesting `/login`, creating endless cycles of redirects: `/login -> [no user] -> [redirect /login] -> /login -> [no user] -> ...`

The most common pattern to handle user authorization is this:

```
// middleware to check user authorization
function checkAuth(req, res, next){
  if(req.user){
    res.locals.username = req.user.username
    next(); // authorization handled successfully, continue processing request
  }else{
    res.redirect('/login');
    // finish processing request without calling next()
  }
}

// we add checkAuth middleware to prevent unauthorized users from accessing server root ('/')
router.get('/', checkAuth, function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('dashboard');
});
// but we don't need to check user authorization on '/login'
router.get('/login', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('...');
});
```

Comment: my problem is req.user is undefined

Comment: @Jennifer what data do you store in `req.user`? Is it an ID of the user? You can populate it using standard means of `req.query` or `req.params`

Comment: @Jennifer nevermind, I saw that you're using it as an object in `req.user.username` and you also mentioned that you have passport middleware. You should consult the docs of whatever authorization method you're using. My (and @mscdex) answer still stands, you'll need the redirection fixed.